# Unbounded operator bounded in a dense subset

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X, Y$ be normed vector spaces, where $X$ is infinite dimensional. Does there exist a linear map $T : X \rightarrow Y$ and a subset $D$ of $X$ such that $D$ is dense in $X$, $T$ is bounded in $D$ (i.e. $\sup _{x\in D, x \neq 0} \frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|}<\infty $), but $T$ is not bounded in $X$?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Matthew's answer reminded me of a fact that makes this easy: if $X$ is a normed space (say, over $\mathbb{R}$) and $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ is a linear functional, then its kernel $\ker f$ is either closed or dense in $X$, depending on whether or not $f$ is continuous (i.e. bounded).  The proof is trivial: $\ker f$ is a subspace of $X$ of codimension 1.  Its closure is a subspace that contains it, so must either be $\ker f$ or $X$.  And of course, a linear functional is continuous iff its kernel is closed.  This is Proposition III.5.2-3 in Conway's *A Course in Functional Analysis*.

So let $f$ be an unbounded linear functional on $X$ (which one can always construct as in Matthew's example), and take $D = \ker f$.  $D$ is dense by the above fact, and $f$ is identically zero on $D$.

Comment: Yeah, nice!  And it answers my questions: $\ker f$ is always a subspace.

Comment: It looks like the best possible answer!

Comment: Wonderful! I choose this as answer for simplicity and for the fact that it works in every infinite dimensional normed space

Comment: I wrote a tiny complement to this answer: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/28415/unbounded-operator-bounded-in-a-dense-subset/28598#28598 

Answer (score 19):

Let $X$ be the space of real polynomials, normed as functions in $C[a,b]$.  Here we want $0 < a < b$ fixed.  Now define $T \colon X \to X$ so that $T(x^n) = 0$ if $n$ is even and $T(x^n) = nx^n$ if $n$ is odd.  Then $T$ is unbounded, but it vanishes on the set of even polynomials.  That set is dense by the Müntz-Szász theorem.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCntz%E2%80%93Sz%C3%A1sz_theorem

I think I have NOT used the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: Nice example.  One could also use Stone-Weierstrass in place of Müntz-Szász: the even polynomials are an algebra that separates points and contains the constants.

Comment: Or even usual Weierstrass theorem (change the variable to $x^2$).

Answer (score 8):

Take a dense linear subspace $Z$ of $X$ such that $X/Z$ is infinite-dimension
(algebraically). Let $x_1,x_2,\ldots$ be a sequence of elements of
$X$ whose images in $X/Z$ are linearly indepdendent. We can define a
linear map on the algebraic span on $Z$ and the $x_j$ which is zero on $Z$
and satisfies $\|Tx_n\|=n\|x_n\|$. Extend this to all $X$ by Zorn's lemma.
Then $T$ is zero on the dense space $Z$ but unbounded on $X$.

Comment: How do you guarantee the existence of such $Z$?  If, say, $X$ is a separable Banach space, you could take $Z$ to be the algebraic span of a countable dense subset, and by the Baire category theorem it has uncountable algebraic codimension.  But I don't see what to do if $X$ is incomplete (and possibly of countable algebraic dimension), or if $X$ is complete but not separable.

Comment: Nate, there are certainly examples of $X$ which work, as you say,
and these include many of the standard examples. For general normed
spaces, I'm not sure. I would suspect that the intersection of
the kernels of a sequence of linearly independent unbounded
functionals might work, but whether there do exists such sequences,
I'm not sure...

Comment: You don't need infinite codimension. Any nontrivial dense subspace  does the job (codimension 1 is enough). And it is easy to construct  a dense subsbace: find one in some closed subspace (e.g. a separable one), then add a complementary subspace.


Answer (score 2):

X is infinite-dimensional, so we can find $(e_n)$ a linearly independent sequence in X; let X' be the span.  By rescaling, we can assume that $\|e_n\|=1$ for each n.
Define $T:X'\rightarrow \mathbb R$ (or $\mathbb C$, or embed into Y if you wish) by $T(e_n) = n$ for each n.  Clearly T is unbounded on X'.

For each finite sum $x=\sum_{n=1}^N x_n e_n$ and $\epsilon>0$, we can choose $a\in\mathbb R$ and $m$ very large with $|a|<\epsilon$ and $T(x) = -am$.  Set $y=x+ae_m$, so $T(y)=T(x)+am=0$ and also $\|x-y\| = |a|<\epsilon$.  Let D' be the collection of all such $y$; as such $x$ exhaust X', we certainly have that D' is dense in X'.

Use Zorn to extend $E=\{e_n\}$ to $E'$ a basis of X.  Extend T to X by setting $T(x)=0$ for $x\in E' \setminus E$.  Let $D = D' + \text{span}(E'\setminus E)$, so D is dense in X, and T is bounded on D; actually T vanishes on D.

Now, D is certainly not a subspace: if you want that as well, I don't know!

Answer (score 1):

This is just to make Nate Eldridge's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28415/unbounded-operator-bounded-in-a-dense-subset/28434#28434) selfcontained.

For any normed vector space $V$ and any $r > 0$, write $V_r$ for the open ball of radius $r$ and center $0$ in $V$.

Let $X$ be a normed vector space, $Y$ a closed space, $Z$ the quotient, $\pi$ the canonical projection, $\tau$ the quotient topology, $\nu$ the topology on $Z$ induced by the quotient norm $$|\pi(x)|:=\inf_{y\in Y}|x+y|.$$

(It's easy to see that this is a norm.)

We claim $\tau=\nu$.

Both topologies are translation invariant.

The set $\{\pi(X_r)\ |\ r > 0\}$ is a basis for the $\tau$-neighborhoods of $0$ in $Z$.

The set $\{(Z_r)\ |\ r > 0\}$ is a basis for the $\nu$-neighborhoods of $0$ in $Z$.

As $\pi(X_r)=Z_r$, we're done.

Answer (score -1):

No.  Bounded means continuous, for linear operators.  If a linear operator is bounded (continuous) on a dense subset, then you can extend it continuously to the whole space, which means it is bounded.

Comment: Your argument shows that $T |_D$ has a bounded extension to all of $X$, but this bounded extension need not be the same as $T$.

Comment: Not quite.  The extension is continuous, but what if that extension is not the original map?  Can't you have two linear maps that agree on a dense set, but differ off that dense set?

Comment: For a concrete example: let X be the subspace of $c_0$ spanned by, say, the sequence $x_0=(1/n)$ and all the sequences which are eventually zero (that latter being the subspace $c_{00}$).  Then you can define a linear map $T:X\rightarrow\mathbb R$ to be zero on $c_{00}$ and anything you like on $x_0$.  But $c_{00}$ is dense in $X$.  Your continuous extension is just the zero map!